# Logitech Gaming Software Macro with random sleep intervals

Tags: random, sleep, repeat, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I am trying to make a LGS macro that repeats pressing the "P" key, while I hold a mouse button. Since I would like this macro to use random sleep intervals between each keypress, I can't use the standard Logitech GUI for that, since this only supports standard intervals. Therefore, it seems I need to use a Lua script to achieve this.

After some research I have come across a script in this forum and modified it that from my understanding should work, but unfortunately doesn't. "My" script only repeats the actions once when I press the mouse button, instead of continuously looping.

I have no idea about programming so please do not feel burdened to stay close to my script if you see a better implementation, even the sleep time parameters are random and I have no idea if those may simulate human behavior.

> ```
> EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
>
> function OnEvent(event, arg)
>    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6 then
>       repeat
>          PressKey("P")
>          Sleep(math.random(27, 43)) 
>          ReleaseKey("p") 
>          Sleep(math.random(29, 36)) 
>       until IsMouseButtonPressed(6)
>    end
> end
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much Egor, that did the trick. I can't believe that the number was the issue, haha. Just for understanding, does "until (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6) == false" make any sense?

Comment: `arg == 6` does make sense, but `IsMouseButtonPressed(6)` does not.

Comment: `until (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 6) == false` this will not work for any arg.  When inside a loop, you're staying in the same event.  To change event, you must exit `OnEvent`

Answer (score 0):

Egor Skriptunoff's comment:

> Only first 5 buttons are available for `IsMouseButtonPressed()`. And the condition in the until statement should look like `until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)` if you want to stop the loop on mouse button release.